# How to set custom image attribute

Tags: magento2, php

I have a web store which I'm trying to link up to an API. The API returns XML, which I parse into custom variables.

The API has a link to an image that I'd like to take and either upload to Magento, or set Magento to look at the image link to find the image when displaying it.

Here's the below code for my custom image attribute.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute($entityTypeId, $attribute, [
            'type'                    => 'varchar',
            'label'                   => 'BGG Image',
            'input'                   => 'media_image',
            'frontend'                => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image',
            'required'                => false,
            'global'                  => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 140,
            'position' => 140,
            'group' => $groupName,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'visible'                 => true,
            'visible_on_front'        => true,
        ]);
```

How do I either:

a) Set the source path for this attribute in the backend

b) Fetch the image in php, and upload it to Magento for the custom product attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//WHERE BGG_IMAGE IS A LINK TO A REMOTE IMG

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$import_path  =  $directory->getRoot() . '/pub/media/import';

//the above will find the absolute path of the import folder

$arr = explode('/', $bgg_image);
$import_filepath = $import_path . '/bgg_img_' . $product_id . '_' . $arr[count($arr)-1];

//the above will create a filepath for the new image in the import folder

file_put_contents($import_filepath, file_get_contents($bgg_image));

//this logic checks if there is currently no data for the image, small_image, 
//thumbnail, and my custom bgg_image role for a product's media gallery images

if($product->getData('image') == 'no_selection') {
    array_push($attribute_codes, 'image');
}
if($product->getData('small_image') == 'no_selection') {
    array_push($attribute_codes, 'small_image');
}
if($product->getData('thumbnail') == 'no_selection') {
    array_push($attribute_codes, 'thumbnail');
}
if($product->getData('bgg_image') == 'no_selection') {
    array_push($attribute_codes, 'bgg_image');
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($import_filepath, $attribute_codes, false, false);
}

//the method $product->addImageToMediaGallery($import_filepath, $attribute_codes, true, 
//false) *should* move the file, but seems to throw an error, so I've had to stick 
//to copying the file and then deleting it from the import folder with an unlink

unlink($import_filepath);

//don't forget to save the product!
```